# ¿Se puede utilizar value en un string-array para asignar un identificador diferente a cada item de un spinner de Android?

Tags: android

sucede que tengo un `Spinner` que cuenta con 4 nombres:

```
   <string-array name="Nombres">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item>Juan</item>
        <item>Pedro</item>
        <item>Carlos</item>
        <item>Jose</item>
    </string-array>
```

Quiero guardarlos en una base de datos de MySQL, pero el campo a guardar es de tipo `int`, ya que es mi llave foránea para relacionar esa tabla con otra. En HTML acostumbro a hacerlo así:

```
   <select class="nombre" name="nombre">
      <option>Seleccione</option>
      <option value="1">Juan</option>
      <option value="2">Pedro</option>
      <option value="3">Carlos</option>
      <option value="3">Jose</option>
   </select>
```

Mi pregunta es si ¿se puede hacer esto en Android?:

```
   <string-array name="Nombres">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item value="1">Juan</item>
        <item value="2">Pedro</item>
        <item value="3">Carlos</item>
        <item value="4">Jose</item>
    </string-array>
```

No he encontrado un ejemplo similar, por eso lo pregunto.

Ahora mismo, lo estoy haciendo así:

```
Spinner spinner_nombres = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp_nombre);

ArrayAdapter adapter_d = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Nombres, R.layout.spiner_item);
spinner_nombres.setAdapter(adapter_d);

String selec = spinner_nombres.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int id_nombre = 0;
        if (selec.equals("Juan")) {
            id_nombre = 1;
        } else
        if (selec.equals("Pedro")) {
            id_nombre = 2;
        }
        else
        if (selec.equals("Carlos")) {
            id_nombre = 3;
        }
        else
        if (selec.equals("Jose")) {
            id_nombre = 4;
        }
```

Y así lo envío al PHP:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idnombre",Integer.toString(id_nombre).trim()));
```

El detalle está en que estoy utilizando 14 `Spinners` en mi aplicación y tanto código me empieza a volver loco, así que agradecería mucho si alguien puede ayudarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a cargar los datos en el Adapter de esta forma , no es posible.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter_d = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Nombres, R.layout.spiner_item);
```

La opción sería crear dos `string-array` dentro de `styles.xml`, uno para los nombres :

```
  <string-array name="nombres">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item>Juan</item>
        <item>Pedro</item>
        <item>Carlos</item>
        <item>Jose</item>
    </string-array>
```

y otro para los valores:

```
  <string-array name="val_nombres">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>
```

En el Adapter cargas los nombres.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter_d = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.nombres, R.layout.spiner_item);
```

para obtener el valor de algun nombre lo haces por medio de la posición:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
int spinner_posicion = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String[] valores_nombre = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.val_nombres);
int valor_nombre = Integer.valueOf(valores_nombre[spinner_posicion]);
```

Se podrían usar los valores del `string-array` conteniendo los atributos que contienen los valores, pero tendrías que implementar tu propio [parser](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xml_parsers.htm).

```
  <string-array name="Nombres">
        <item>Seleccione</item>
        <item value="1">Juan</item>
        <item value="2">Pedro</item>
        <item value="3">Carlos</item>
        <item value="4">Jose</item>
    </string-array>
```

En realidad es mucho más sencillo y mejor performance realizar la opción de dos `string-array`.

Comment: Gracias por responder @Elenasys oye tengo una duda es necesario crear los dos `String array` en styles.xml es que yo lo tengo en strings.xml

Comment: Es válido crearlos en strings.xml, o podrías poner los arreglos en el código. Me parece que lees una BD MySQL por lo tanto también podrías obtener un List<String> con los valores y agregarlos a tu Adapter.

Comment: duda aclarada pero ahora veo otro problemilla digamos que en el caso que no se elija ninguna opcion del spinner enviaria un 0 cierto? y yo no quiero que si no selecciona ninguna opcion pues simplemente no envie nada, crees que debo utilizar getOnItemSelectedListener()?

Comment: Disculpa envie el comentario y aun no lo habia terminado de escribir, ya lo edite

Comment: Me parece que te refieres a "setOnItemSelectedListener()" , al usar este listener implementas onItemSelected() que también recibe la posición (tercer párametro), podrías validar si es 0 no realice la acción =)

Answer (score 1):

No hay forma sencilla de hacerlo en un fichero XML. Como alternativa, puedes utilizar un `List<Pair<Integer, String>>` llenándolo por código.

La documentación de `Pair` está aquí: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html